# C# IQueryableto to IEnumerable using Linq expressions and class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a class which should take the query results from a database using a join.

My class is:

```
`
   public class StepTwo 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Party { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string Account { get; set; }
        public double? Amount { get; set; }
    }
`
```

I have then created a method which will return the results:

```
  public IEnumerable<StageTwo> StepTwo()
    {
        var queryJoin = (from inn in db.Input.Take(10)
                        join yacc in db.AccY on inn.Action equals yacc.Action
                        orderby inn.Id descending
                        select new 
                        {
                            inn.Id,
                            inn.XParty,
                            inn.Curr,
                            yacc.Action,
                            inn.Amount
                        });
         return queryJoin;
    }
```

In other methods where I did not use a join, this worked fine but now it is not working. I have the error message on the `return queryJoin;` stating:

```
`
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: int Id, string XParty, string Curr, string YAction, double? Amount>>' to '
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.StepTwo>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`
```

I know the class names are a bit different from the database names but I have tried to change them to match. Based on the error above, I assume it's something else.

Any advise would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why select an anonymous class instead of `select new StageTwo { Id = inn.Id ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is telling you that `queryJoin` is an anonymous type, but you are trying to force it to be an `IEnumerable<StageTwo>`, and C# can't make that conversion.

The reason `queryJoin` is an anonymous type is because you've not defined it in your linq query. So to fix it, instead of this:

```
select new 
{
    inn.Id,
    inn.XParty,
    inn.Curr,
    yacc.Action,
    inn.Amount
});
```

You'd want this:

```
select new StepTwo 
{
    Id = inn.Id,
    Party = inn.XParty,
    Currency = inn.Curr,
    Account = yacc.Action,
    Amount = inn.Amount
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! still getting to grips with this and this was a big help. Take care bud.

Comment: happy to help :)